# Trying to inject javascript to every page

Tags: proxy, javascript

Hie.

I'm working on a JS library that makes changes to dom elements and I would like to be able to show people it's effect in my site.

I'm trying to setup some sort of proxy similar to a transparent proxy that I can call him with the url I want to test and it will inject the JS to the site I'm in.

The idea is opening an iframe to the proxy server with a query parameter of the url we want to test. then the server would pull the data, inject a js file to the page and will return the data. 
As this should run in the client's browser, I can't make them update the proxy setting.

I thought about using Privoxy or similar proxy servers but couldn't find the right config/feature that will allow me to see the updated data in my browser as a regular client would.

I've also used node.js redirect but several sites blocked that access - not sure if it was port forwarding or anything else.

How can I create a dynamic proxy server that I can send the url to and get the site with the injected javascript?

Thanks in advance,
Shahar